# FFmpeg (MacPorts) - libfaac missing, need new audio encoder

Tags: ffmpeg, macports, video-encoding

I am so confused.

I am trying a quite simple FFMpeg command to transcode a movie file to a x264/AAC mp4 file via the command line (for Vimeo upload). (Mountain Lion/Macports)

```
ffmpeg -i INPUT.AVI -vcodec libx264 -acodec libfaac -preset hq -s hd720 -b 5000k -ar 44100 -ab 320k OUTPUT.mp4
```

Problem: `FFMpeg` cannot find the `libfaac` library. I have read it has recently been taken out. True? I also have read that I better use `NeroAACEnc` or `libvo_aacenc` anyways as they might be better quality-wise.

How do I:

1. Add `NeroAACEnc` and/or `libvo_aacenc` to my system?
2. What is the correct command line to invoke one of these when they are installed? I have seen solutions with pipes etc.

Command line, Linux and Unix work is all a bit new to me, so I cannot work out what internet is telling me to do. Macports confuses me a bit too.

Looking forward to your pro help here.

Here is the complete iTerm2 output:

```
ffmpeg -i test.mp4 -vcodec libx264 -acodec libfaac -preset hq -s hd720 -b 5000k -ar 44100 -ab 320k OUTPUT.mp4
ffmpeg version 0.11.1.git Copyright (c) 2000-2012 the FFmpeg developers
  built on Aug  4 2012 11:25:44 with clang 4.0 ((tags/Apple/clang-421.0.57))
  configuration: --prefix=/opt/local --enable-swscale --enable-avfilter --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libvorbis --enable-libtheora --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libmodplug --enable-libvpx --enable-libspeex --mandir=/opt/local/share/man --enable-shared --enable-pthreads --cc=/usr/bin/clang --enable-gpl --enable-postproc --enable-libx264 --enable-libxvid --arch=x86_64 --enable-yasm
  libavutil      51. 65.100 / 51. 65.100
  libavcodec     54. 41.100 / 54. 41.100
  libavformat    54. 17.100 / 54. 17.100
  libavdevice    54.  1.100 / 54.  1.100
  libavfilter     3.  2.100 /  3.  2.100
  libswscale      2.  1.100 /  2.  1.100
  libswresample   0. 15.100 /  0. 15.100
  libpostproc    52.  0.100 / 52.  0.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'test.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp42
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: mp42isomavc1
    creation_time   : 2012-04-27 12:10:05
    encoder         : HandBrake 0.9.6 2012022800
  Duration: 00:00:32.83, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 3241 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1280x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 3074 kb/s, 29.97 fps, 30 tbr, 90k tbn, 180k tbc
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2012-04-27 12:10:05
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, mono, s16, 164 kb/s
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2012-04-27 12:10:05
Please use -b:a or -b:v, -b is ambiguous
Unknown encoder 'libfaac'
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

With slhck's help, I found the missing libfaac solution. I had to reinstall the ffmpeg macport with the following variant chosen to allow libfaac to install (which has been taken out of the standard package due to licensing issues)

`sudo port install ffmpeg +nonfree`

...will install libfaac as well.

Comment: Feel free to drop a comment for remaining questions, or even post a new one!

Comment: `libfaac` can only support a maximum quality of 152kbit/s which is on the low side. Hence I am trying to encode using the `NeroAACEnc` or `libvo_aacenc`libraries instead. How can I compile these in  Mac OS to use in my encoding?

Comment: Good idea.
I have found `afconvert` to be a viable alternative for AAC encoding. How would a simple complete `ffmpeg` command look like using this encoder for audio and same x264 settings as abobe? I am fiddling with pipe outputs and stuff, I cannot get it right.

Comment: @LordNeckbeard I can't find that edit from your profile, but I do it myself or approve it again for you if you let me know. We always appreciate your contributions — I'm sorry if another user rejected that edit. Or you could post your own answer here.

Comment: Its still running, so not sure yet that it'll work, but it looks like it will.  One line answers are cool.